# Access eigenvalues

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to get the smallest the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a covariance matrix:

```
    Eigen::Matrix3d covariance_matrix; //has to be Matrix3d
    double minEigenValue = 0;
    int minEigenVectorIndex = 0;
    //compute covariance matrix
    Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix3d > solver(covariance_matrix);
    Eigen::Matrix eigenvalues = solver.eigenvalues();
    // Eigen::Matrix3d eigenvalues = solver.eigenvalues(); results in an error
    for(int i = 0; i < 3;i++)
    {
//How do I access the eigenvalues? This fails. eigenvalues[0][i] also fails
        if(eigenvalues(0,i) > minEigenValue) 
        {
            minEigenValue = eigenvalues(0,i);
            minEigenVectorIndex = i;
        }
    }
    // somehow get pair of vector[0], vector[1], vector[2]: 
   //solver.eigenvectors().col(minEigenVectorIndex);
```

I have read through the documentation quite a lot, but couldn't find a clear example / explanation
How do I access the eigenvectors and values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>,3,1> eigenvalues = solver.eigenvalues();
    Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>,3,3> eigenvec = solver.eigenvectors();`

Comment: Tried `Vector3d` already, but if I'm trying to use anything else than `Eigen::Matrix`, I'm getting `/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:292:7: error: ‘YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY’ is not a member of ‘Eigen::internal::static_assertion<false>’
`

Comment: You are right. I copy/pasted the code from mine, but here I use the self adjoint solver. I'll edit to have the correct answer.

Comment: Alternatively you could just use `auto eigenvals = solver.eigenvalues();`

Comment: Be carefull with Eigen and `auto` though. `auto` does not play well with expression templates.

Comment: I just tried with auto and Visual C++ 2015 and it compiles.

Comment: Yes, this was indeed the problem, sorry I forgot to update on the issue.
Alternatively (although less explicit for the answer): `Eigen::Vector3cd` and `Eigen::Matrix3cd` can be used